# Catching all google search results in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, bing

I am writing a script in ruby which requires me to search google for particular keyword, and catch and store all returned results url (which are in thousands) for further process. How do I achieve that in Ruby. Are there any gem? I would also consider option of using Bing API.

Answer (score 1):

These two look awesome.

https://github.com/mattetti/ruby-web-search

https://github.com/visionmedia/google-search

Comment: Thanks Phil. Does google detect that it is not human but some script fetching search results if I use ruby-web-search?

Comment: Good question. It is using Google Search API, and may be a subject to 100 searches/day limitation or will require using a paid service.

Comment: Then I think using Bing API would be better option because if at any point google detects (which I think they will) that it is a script they will throw me away. Between do you know paramater for pagination option in rbing gem?

Comment: Try adding `:first => 11` to search options for second page, hence I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: Nope tried that already. I also tried :page_number, :start_with, :start_index, :page, :onpage, :inpage but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Good practice in OSS community is to fork, dive into source code, add all these options and send a pull request. You won't spend too much time on that.

Comment: We've also released our own gem (https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-ruby) that doesn't have limitations.